# I am trying to deploy supabase in environment. Supabase real time is failing because of ipv6. How to disable ipv6 in supabase?

Tags: supabase

I am trying to deploy supabase in environment. Supabase real time is failing because of ipv6. How to disable ipv6 in supabase?
Error message below:
22:43:42.151 [error] Failed to start Ranch listener RealtimeWeb.Endpoint.HTTP in :ranch_tcp:listen([{:cacerts, :...}, {:key, :...}, {:cert, :...}, :inet6, {:port, 8080}]) for reason :eafnosupport (address family not supported by protocol family)

Trying to deploy supabase in our kube environment.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime currently only supports ipv6 but ipv4 is on the todo list internally.

PRs welcomed!